# Access File from sharepoint list using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, graph

I am able to access list with this URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/collaboration.sharepoint.com,acg7dc07-275d-4d76-8f60-58ea3b489989,9cd9b335-0955-4af5-8a3b-1546fcdc728a/lists/9844ca7d-300c-43d9-8537-86e194de7203

But unable to access file item from here. Please can you provide graph query for this."children" element is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get SharePoint file with Graph API, you should take a reference to this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0

Demo:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/b57886ef-vvvv-4d56-ad29-27266638ac3b,b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-vvvv-f6600fd6cc14/drives/b!74Z4tSpMVk2tKScmZjisO1AULbZvjudLhKP2YA_WzBRoT2if-9ngRbwNEoecoTO3/root/children
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/b57886ef-vvvv-4d56-ad29-27266638ac3b,b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-vvvv-f6600fd6cc14/drives/b!74Z4tSpMVk2tKScmZjisO1AULbZvjudLhKP2YA_WzBRoT2if-9ngRbwNEoecoTO3/items/01ATCFPNRYOGQCUL46MZDI6LKDDX35NQPB/children
```